# grails 2.3.x: Strange behavior with autogenerated controller

Tags: grails, grails-2.3

A fresh grails 2.3.x project. Im using autogenerated controller and views for a domain class. One (not null) property i want to set directly in controller, so i removed the input field from the _form.gsp.

Domain class:

```
class Demo {
    String demo
    String status

    static constraints = {
       demo   nullable: false
       status nullable: false

}
```

In form i only fill the demo field.

Autogenerated controller results in:

```
...
@Transactional
def save(Demo demoInstance) {
    if (demoInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    // set the status property to "test"
    demoInstance.status = "test"

    println "1 STATUS: ${demoInstance.status}"

    if (demoInstance.hasErrors()) {
        println "2 STATUS: ${demoInstance.status}"
        respond demoInstance.errors, view: 'create'
        return
    }
    println "3 STATUS: ${demoInstance.status}"
    ...
```

Fill the form and leave the status property blank results in 
println 1 -> status = 'test'
println 2 -> status = 'test'
Redirect to create page with a message: "Property [status] of class [Demo] cannot be null"

When i change the controller as in grails 2.2.x:

```
...
@Transactional
def save() {
    def demoInstance = new Demo(params)

    if (demoInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    // set the status property to "test"
    demoInstance.status = "test"

    println "1 STATUS: ${demoInstance.status}"

    if (demoInstance.hasErrors()) {
        println "2 STATUS: ${demoInstance.status}"
        respond demoInstance.errors, view: 'create'
        return
    }
    println "3 STATUS: ${demoInstance.status}"
    ...
```

This results in the expected output:
println 1 -> status = 'test'
println 3 -> status = 'test'
And the input is stored in Database.

Can anyone explain this behavior? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. Do not know the exact reason, but what works is:
bindData(demoInstance, [status: 'test'])
Grails 2.3 has a new DataBinding. you can use the old Spring style if you set
grails.databinding.useSpringBinder = true
in Config.groovy
Using this SpringBinder, this issue does not occur.

Comment: Thx pereiss, "grails.databinding.useSpringBinder = true" solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you're seeing the behavior you're seeing with the 2.2.x code, but the 2.3.x behavior looks correct to me regardless of which data binder you use. Data binding occurs before the controller action is called and since you left a property unset, the instance has a validation error. You then set a valid value but don't call `validate()` or `save()`, so there's no reason to expect that `hasErrors()` would change from false to true.

If you add

```
demoInstance.validate()
```

after

```
demoInstance.status = "test"
```

then I would expect to see the output you're seeing in your 2.2.x version (although again, without a `validate` or `save` call I can't imagine why it would work in 2.2 either).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the clarification. So hasErrors() is a getter Method and does not validate the domain object? The validation will be done automatically after grails bind the properties to the object?

Comment: Right - it would be bad for `hasErrors()` to have the side effect of performing validation; getters should not make changes. The only method that validates is `validate`.